# Spark sesssion in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow

I'm trying to start a spark session in an Airflow DAG, and this is the error I'm getting

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/wip_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 417, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 106, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

The error seems to be with the line

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Is there something in particular that needs to be done before you create a spark instance on Airflow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can't say exactly but check with environmental variables set properly or not eg JAVA_HOME etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your spark code inside of a `PythonOperator()` task?

This error might be related to that.

If that is the case, you can use the SparkSubmitOperator() instead.

First of all, install the provider package for it

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark
```

After installation, you can take a look on this example and adjust you DAG accordingly.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from datetime import datetime
from src.test import logger_test

# initializing the default arguments that we'll pass to our DAG
default_arguments = {
    'owner': 'admin',
    # This is the beginning, for more see: https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 5, 2)
}

# Let's define our DAG
dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'test_spark_operator_dag',
    default_args = default_arguments,
    description = 'This DAG is made for testing the configuration of the pipeline',
    # This interval is defined with CRON type. For more info go: https://crontab.guru/examples.html
    schedule_interval = "@daily", 
    # If DAG fails to run, catchup will make sure it is tried again.
    catchup = False,
)

task_main_dag_6 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'Logger_Test_New',
    python_callable=logger_test,
    retries=0,
    dag = dag,
)

task_spark_dag_6 = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id = 'Spark_Pipeline_Testing',
    conn_id='spark_local',
    application='dags/src/spark.py',
    packages='org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1',
    jars="/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar",
    total_executor_cores=4,
    name='Spark_Pipeline_Testing',    
    dag = dag_6,
)

task_end_dag_6 = EmptyOperator(
    task_id = 'End',
    dag=dag_6
)

task_main_dag_6  >> task_spark_dag_6 >> task_end_dag_6
```

For more information you can take a look on [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator/index.html) and [a use case.](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/use-sparksubmitoperator-airflow-dag)